# Materializecss - prop radio checkbox with jQuery on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize, prop

I have 1 radio item, and I want it to behave like a checkbox. So now, it gets selected but I couldn't bind it to prop state on click.

So I want to achieve is: when clicked on radio btn, it reverses its checked state.

Here is what I tried:

```
<form action="#">
    <p>
      <input name="group" type="radio" id="test" />
      <label for="test">Red</label>
    </p>
</form>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').click(function() {
        $('#test').prop('checked', !$('#test').prop('checked'))
  })
})
```

What interesting is, if I create another button and bind it to change `checked` value, it works

```
<button id="faker" type="button">
    Faker Btn
</button>

$('#faker').click(function() {
  $('#test').prop('checked', !$('#test').prop('checked'))
})
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/55L52yww/81/

Comment: On first time click, you are checking if its checked. It will be always unchecked as click event not completed.

Comment: Can you please take a look on fiddle? I tried various combinations but no luck :/

Comment: It doesn't reverse the state of radio `checked` on click on itself, like the faker button does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A radio can behave like a checkbox if you add a state attribute to the radio element like in:

```
<input name="group" type="radio" id="test" data-state="false"/>
```

Now, you can save the last state and compare with the current value in order to decide the action to do.

The snippet:

```js
$('#test').on('click', function(e) {
  var a = $(this).data('state');
  var b = $(this).prop('checked');
  if (a && b) {
      b = false;
      $(this).prop('checked', b);
  }
  $(this).data('state', b);
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<form action="#">
    <p>
        <input name="group" type="radio" id="test" data-state="false"/>
        <label for="test">Red</label>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Ahh a similar answer while I was typing mine.. great minds think alike :)

Answer (score 1):

When you get into the function that was triggered by the radio button itself, the state of the `checked` property has already changed. That causes a problem on the first click, because the new state is `true` and therefore your function sets it back to `false`.

You can solve this by keeping track of the `checked` state yourself in a separate `data` attribute and checking that instead.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#test').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data('previousState')) {
      $this.prop('checked',false).data('previousState',false);
    }
    else {
      $this.prop('checked',true).data('previousState',true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <p>
    <input name="group1" type="radio" id="test" />
    <label for="test">Red</label>
  </p>
</form>
```